# Combining 3 tables in the same database, while limiting the scope of the search time

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

Combining 3 tables in the same database: The 3 tables under the same database called Files - the table names im interested in are RXInboundFileQueue, EligibilityFileQueue, and CostFileQueue. All 3 tables share the OriginalName and FileCatalogedOn columns. For an output I'm looking for a query that combines all 3 tables into 1 view and displays each tables files listed within the last 7 days. The code below I wrote outputs every file from each table starting from todays date - but I can't figure a good way to write an outer join to merge these results and only look at a 7 day look behind.

```
DECLARE @DateFrom DateTime = (SELECT CAST(GetDate() as Date))
DECLARE @DateTo DateTime = (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateFrom))

SELECT
    OriginalName,  
    FileCatalogedOn
FROM RXInboundFileQueue
ORDER BY FileCatalogedOn DESC

DECLARE @DateFrom DateTime = (SELECT CAST(GetDate() as Date))
DECLARE @DateTo DateTime = (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateFrom))

SELECT
    OriginalName,
    FileCatalogedOn
FROM EligibilityInboundFileQueue
ORDER BY FileCatalogedOn DESC

DECLARE @DateFrom DateTime = (SELECT CAST(GetDate() as Date))
DECLARE @DateTo DateTime = (SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateFrom))

SELECT
    OriginalName,
    FileCatalogedOn
FROM CostFileInboundFileQueue
ORDER BY FileCatalogedOn DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    OriginalName,  
    FileCatalogedOn,
    'rx' as filetype
FROM RXInboundFileQueue
WHERE FILECatalogedOn >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GetDate())


UNION ALL

SELECT
    OriginalName,
    FileCatalogedOn,
    'eligibility' as filetype
FROM EligibilityInboundFileQueue
WHERE FILECatalogedOn >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GetDate())

UNION ALL

SELECT
    OriginalName,
    FileCatalogedOn,
    'costfile' as filetype
FROM CostFileInboundFileQueue
WHERE FILECatalogedOn >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GetDate())

ORDER BY FileCatalogedOn DESC
```

Comment: Im getting a console read out error that says: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.

Comment: Not sure what the issue with the UNION error is. Ran without it produces the 3 table views

Comment: As an update the problem I found was doing multiple Order By calls throws off the UNION statement, so leaving only the last Order By statement will produce the correct results

Comment: @Mistymanor -- yes the issue was the order by (which makes sense if you think about what union does) -- sorry I was away all day and just saw your comments now.